# How do you update ASP.NET web forms from different threads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms

In the last few days I've been trying to learn how to use ASP.NET Web Forms together with multithreading the hard way by building a simple applet using both and I've been struggling with aspects of interactions between different threads and the UI.

I've resolved some multithreading issues in some other questions (and also learned after waaaaaay too long that web forms and WPF are not the same thing) but now I'm running into trouble finding the best way to update UI elements based on data acquired in multiple threads.

Here's my code:

**Default.aspx**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private NlSearch _search;
    private static int _counter = 0;
    private static SortedList<long, SearchResult> resultsList = new SortedList<long, SearchResult>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _search = new NlSearch();
    }

    protected void AddSearchMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = SearchForm.Text;
        new Task(() => MakeRequest(text));
    }

    protected void UpdateMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultsLabel.Text = "";
        foreach (var v in resultsList.Values)
        {
            resultsLabel.Text += v.SearchTerm + ": " + v.Count + " occurances<br/>";
        }
    }

    protected void ClearSearchMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultsLabel.Text = "";
        resultsList.Clear();
    }

    protected void MakeRequest(string text)
    {
        _counter++;
        SearchResult s = new SearchResult
        {
            SearchTerm = text,
            Count = _search.MakeRequests(text)
        };
        resultsList.Add(_counter, s);
    }
}
```

I've tried quite a few versions of the same basic thing. NlSearch.MakeRequest (called by MakeRequests) sends an HTTP POST request to an outside web site imitating a search bar input, and then extracts an integer from the markup indicating how many results came back.

The current simple UI revolves around a SearchForm textfield, an "Add Search" button, an "Update Label" button a "Clear Search" method, and a ResultsLabel that displays results. The AddSearch button creates a new task that calls MakeRequest, which calls the method to send the HTTP request and then stores the results in the order they were sent in a static sorted list.

So now ideally in a good UI I would like to just update the label every time a thread returns, however I've tried using ContinueWhenAll and a few other task functions and the problem seems to be that other threads do not have the ability to change the UI.

I have also tried running a new thread on page load that updates the label every few seconds, but this likewise failed.

Because I haven't been able to implement this correctly, I've had to use the "Update Label" button which literally just tells the label to display what's currently in the static list. I would really like to get rid of this button but I can't figuer out how to get my threads to make UI changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, trying to do threading in a web app is a bad idea.  Web servers are designed for this, but spinning off new threads or processes should be avoided if at all possible.  While there used to be a mechanism (and maybe there still is) to "push" results to a client, there are better solutions available today.

What you're describing is exactly the problem that AJAX is intended to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned WPF in your question -- are you perhaps instead looking for a Windows application, like WinForms? I think that perhaps the term "web forms" has confused the situation. Web forms are just webpages with some (okay, a lot) of added in Microsoft functionality.

It sounds like you're trying to send updates to a webpage from a thread in code. The web doesn't work that way. I'd suggest reading through the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you're actually trying to design webpages. Other answers have suggested AJAX functionality (which is where the web page executes some JavaScript that goes out and talks to a web server).

Comment: So is there no simple way in this application to periodically update / update the label without the user explicitly pressing a button? I just don't really follow why it isn't possible to do in a C# backend without using AJAX. Why can the main thread update UI elements but there is no way for other threads to do so, and given that, is there really no easy way in the c# to just add a simple update routine?

Comment: Or, in other words, I'd rather use a simple workaround if one exists rather than delving into learning AJAX at the moment.

Comment: Although this seems simple, the underlying structure of the web just flat out doesn't allow for it. The main thread updates UI elements in a specific (albeit complex) order and then stops execution. The `Unload` event (featured in the life cycle overview above) stops communications with the page itself. Web pages aren't meant to be treated like windows forms, where you can update a client by broadcasting an update message to a listener. Clients have to check in with servers on the web. That's just the nature of HTTP.

Comment: Continuing: This is specifically why AJAX exists. The hacks you'll see in ASP.NET -- things like `UpdatePanels` and `AutoPostBack` controls -- all use JavaScript and AJAX to communicate with the server behind the scenes. Interactive websites use JavaScript, jQuery, or other JavaScript libraries to abstract away the underlying difficulties in creating AJAX requests.

Comment: @ProtonBetaDecay: What you want to do is not possible because of the way HTTP works: you open a connection, make a request, receive results, and close the connection.  At that point there is no more interaction between the client and the server.  There is no simple workaround to the way HTTP works, and if you did find some hack it would probably be treated as a security problem and patched pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever hear about AJAX before? I think you're a thinking as application dev instead of web dev.

Comment: I've heard of it but haven't used it. What do you mean by application dev instead of web dev?

Comment: Yes, the web is stateless usually you use the Session to maintain the State of the web application. In your particular case, AJAX help you to develop an asynchronous behavior in you web app (you can do several request, getting the results and displaying in the page those results). The asynchronous event based programming is mainly focus to develop desktop apps or fill the gap in the mobile apps.

Comment: I found a way to do it asynchronous stuff in the server side. It's using ASP .Net MVC 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your code asynchonous you may want to use the `Async Await` keywords instead of managing threads yourself. [See information about Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

Do not let your threads get tangled up ;)

Comment: Is this not available in VS2010 / .NET versions earlier than 4.5?

Comment: That is true, but it is not in the question. Framework 4 is possible through the base class library: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx